# MacBook Pro: Unable to connect to iOS or Android hotspot

Tags: networking, macos

I am using a MacBook Pro 13" 2017 running the latest version of macOS Catalina 10.15.6 (19G2021).

I have tried to connect to a mobile hotspot of an Android device (Samsung A20 with all software updates installed) and iOS device (iPhone 6 with all software updates installed) but neither of them work for the MacBook Pro. Other devices can connect to the respective hotspot without any issues.

The generic error message I receive is:

"Failed to enable Personal Hotspot on iPhone - Check to see if the device is turned on and in range of your computer"

**EDIT: I have been able to resolve the issue by performing another PRAM reset. The first one must have been unsuccessful.**

Here is the wifi.log from when I attempted to connect to the iPhone hotspot this morning:

```
Driver Event: <airportd[2353]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: SCAN_CACHE_UPDATED (en0)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Successful cache-assisted scan request for WiFiAgent with channels {(
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3637e50> [channelNumber=7(2GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3643c90> [channelNumber=8(2GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3643dc0> [channelNumber=9(2GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3643f20> [channelNumber=10(2GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3644080> [channelNumber=11(2GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3644260> [channelNumber=12(2GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, active]
)} took 0.2930 seconds, returned 2 results
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 261 (locationd)
Driver Event: <airportd[2353]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: SCAN_CACHE_UPDATED (en0)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Successful cache-assisted scan request for WiFiAgent with channels {(
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3644370> [channelNumber=13(2GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a363f590> [channelNumber=36(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a364b3b0> [channelNumber=40(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a363d780> [channelNumber=44(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a364be20> [channelNumber=48(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a36450a0> [channelNumber=149(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, active]
)} took 0.2926 seconds, returned 4 results
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 261 (locationd)
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> STOP BROWSING FOR TETHER DEVICES event received from airportd
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Reviewing nearby PH results: {(
    <CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a363bab0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]
)}
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Adding PH [<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a363bab0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Derived preferred PH candidates: (
    "<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a363bab0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]",
    "<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a363bab0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]"
)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Show user notification for <CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a363bab0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-HOTSPOT COMPLETED for interface en0, took 5.0521 seconds, returned 'failure', show user notification
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-JOIN COMPLETED for interface en0, took 5.0570 seconds, returned result 'failure', error [NO ERROR]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCInterfaceContext __scheduleAutoJoinRetryWithInterval:]: Auto-join will retry in 1.000000 seconds.
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Not updating scan result: a menu item is focused
Driver Event: <airportd[2353]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: SCAN_CACHE_UPDATED (en0)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Successful cache-assisted scan request for WiFiAgent with channels {(
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a363ffc0> [channelNumber=153(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a363da10> [channelNumber=157(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a363f2d0> [channelNumber=161(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a364b0f0> [channelNumber=165(5GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, active],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a364c240> [channelNumber=52(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, DFS],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3724af0> [channelNumber=56(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS]
)} took 0.4353 seconds, returned 3 results
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 261 (locationd)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Successful cache-assisted scan request for WiFiAgent with channels {(
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3724c50> [channelNumber=60(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, DFS],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3722510> [channelNumber=64(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3716c70> [channelNumber=100(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, DFS],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3720fe0> [channelNumber=104(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a37299d0> [channelNumber=108(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, DFS],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a372a160> [channelNumber=112(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS]
)} took 0.7078 seconds, returned 0 results
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-JOIN trigger requested (Retry Timer)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> user: REMOVED
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem clearScanCacheWithInterfaceName:daemon:familyAndDriver:connection:error:]: Clearing family+driver scan cache for interface en0
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-JOIN STARTED for interface en0 (Retry Timer)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT RECOVERY MODE => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Reviewing the preferred networks list
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Ignoring disabled network ['REMOVED' (wifi.ssid.44697665727365436f) - WPA2 Enterprise]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT LOGINWINDOW MODE 802.1X => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT LINK DOWN RECOVERY => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT MAINTENANCE WAKE => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT PERSONAL HOTSPOT TRANSITION => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> No known colocated network for preferred network (null)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT MORE-PREFERRED USER MODE 802.1X NETWORKS => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT SYSTEM MODE 802.1X => continuing
Info: <airportd[2353]> systemWokenByWiFi: System wake reason: <EC.LidOpen>, was not woken by WiFi
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT WOW => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT WATCHDOG RESET => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT PNL Changed => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTOJOIN => auto-join using the entire preferred networks list
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Empty preferred networks list, will not continue auto-join
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-HOTSPOT STARTED for interface en0 (mode=AskToJoin)
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> START BROWSING FOR TETHER DEVICES event received from airportd
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> WiFi menu extra did close
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> STOP SCANNING request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> current=(no_assoc) changed=(scan)
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> JOIN request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> CONNECT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> current=(no_assoc, join) changed=(join)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Successful cache-assisted scan request for WiFiAgent with channels {(
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a372a580> [channelNumber=116(5GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, DFS],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a36444d0> [channelNumber=132(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(+1)}, DFS],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3644b20> [channelNumber=136(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a3644790> [channelNumber=140(5GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}, DFS],
    <CWChannel: 0x7f90a36448f0> [channelNumber=144(5GHz), channelWidth={40MHz(-1)}, DFS]
)} took 0.5899 seconds, returned 0 results
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> ENABLE TETHER DEVICE event received from airportd
BTC: <airportd[2353]> BluetoothCoexStatusMonitoringCallback: Bluetooth Status Notification
BTC: <airportd[2353]> BluetoothCoexStatusNotificationProcess: BT: ON, Num HID Devices is <0>, Num SCO Devices is <0>, Num A2DP Devices is <0>, Bluetooth Bandwidth Utilization is <53>, LWM <5>, HWM <26>
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
BTC: <airportd[2353]> BluetoothCoexStatusMonitoringCallback: Bluetooth Status Notification
BTC: <airportd[2353]> BluetoothCoexStatusNotificationProcess: BT: ON, Num HID Devices is <0>, Num SCO Devices is <0>, Num A2DP Devices is <0>, Bluetooth Bandwidth Utilization is <8>, LWM <5>, HWM <26>
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
BTC: <airportd[2353]> BluetoothCoexStatusMonitoringCallback: Bluetooth Status Notification
BTC: <airportd[2353]> BluetoothCoexStatusNotificationProcess: BT: ON, Num HID Devices is <0>, Num SCO Devices is <0>, Num A2DP Devices is <0>, Bluetooth Bandwidth Utilization is <8>, LWM <5>, HWM <26>
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> STOP BROWSING FOR TETHER DEVICES event received from airportd
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Reviewing nearby PH results: {(
    <CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a3725aa0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]
)}
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Adding PH [<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a3725aa0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Derived preferred PH candidates: (
    "<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a3725aa0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]",
    "<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a3725aa0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]"
)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Show user notification for <CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a3725aa0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-HOTSPOT COMPLETED for interface en0, took 5.0108 seconds, returned 'failure', show user notification
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-JOIN COMPLETED for interface en0, took 5.0162 seconds, returned result 'failure', error [NO ERROR]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCInterfaceContext __scheduleAutoJoinRetryWithInterval:]: Auto-join will retry in 5.000000 seconds.
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> -[CWAutoHotspotNotifications showAutoHotspotNotificationForTetherDevice:retry:interfaceName:]_block_invoke: Notification is already pending/delivered for this interface. Ignoring.
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-JOIN trigger requested (Retry Timer)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> user: REMOVED
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem clearScanCacheWithInterfaceName:daemon:familyAndDriver:connection:error:]: Clearing family+driver scan cache for interface en0
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-JOIN STARTED for interface en0 (Retry Timer)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT RECOVERY MODE => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Reviewing the preferred networks list
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Ignoring disabled network ['REMOVED' (wifi.ssid.44697665727365436f) - WPA2 Enterprise]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT LOGINWINDOW MODE 802.1X => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT LINK DOWN RECOVERY => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT MAINTENANCE WAKE => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT PERSONAL HOTSPOT TRANSITION => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> No known colocated network for preferred network (null)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT MORE-PREFERRED USER MODE 802.1X NETWORKS => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT SYSTEM MODE 802.1X => continuing
Info: <airportd[2353]> systemWokenByWiFi: System wake reason: <EC.LidOpen>, was not woken by WiFi
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT WOW => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT WATCHDOG RESET => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT PNL Changed => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTOJOIN => auto-join using the entire preferred networks list
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Empty preferred networks list, will not continue auto-join
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-HOTSPOT STARTED for interface en0 (mode=AskToJoin)
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> START BROWSING FOR TETHER DEVICES event received from airportd
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> STOP BROWSING FOR TETHER DEVICES event received from airportd
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Reviewing nearby PH results: {(
    <CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a354e5f0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]
)}
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Adding PH [<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a354e5f0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Derived preferred PH candidates: (
    "<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a354e5f0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]",
    "<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a354e5f0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]"
)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Show user notification for <CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a354e5f0> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-HOTSPOT COMPLETED for interface en0, took 5.0103 seconds, returned 'failure', show user notification
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-JOIN COMPLETED for interface en0, took 5.0137 seconds, returned result 'failure', error [NO ERROR]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCInterfaceContext __scheduleAutoJoinRetryWithInterval:]: Auto-join will retry in 5.000000 seconds.
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> -[CWAutoHotspotNotifications showAutoHotspotNotificationForTetherDevice:retry:interfaceName:]_block_invoke: Notification is already pending/delivered for this interface. Ignoring.
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-JOIN trigger requested (Retry Timer)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> user: REMOVED
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem clearScanCacheWithInterfaceName:daemon:familyAndDriver:connection:error:]: Clearing family+driver scan cache for interface en0
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-JOIN STARTED for interface en0 (Retry Timer)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT RECOVERY MODE => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Reviewing the preferred networks list
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Ignoring disabled network ['REMOVED' (wifi.ssid.44697665727365436f) - WPA2 Enterprise]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT LOGINWINDOW MODE 802.1X => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT LINK DOWN RECOVERY => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT MAINTENANCE WAKE => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT PERSONAL HOTSPOT TRANSITION => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> No known colocated network for preferred network (null)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT MORE-PREFERRED USER MODE 802.1X NETWORKS => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT SYSTEM MODE 802.1X => continuing
Info: <airportd[2353]> systemWokenByWiFi: System wake reason: <EC.LidOpen>, was not woken by WiFi
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT WOW => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT WATCHDOG RESET => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> NOT PNL Changed => continuing
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTOJOIN => auto-join using the entire preferred networks list
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Empty preferred networks list, will not continue auto-join
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-HOTSPOT STARTED for interface en0 (mode=AskToJoin)
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> START BROWSING FOR TETHER DEVICES event received from airportd
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <Wi-Fi Menu Extra[307]> Updating WiFi scan result menu items
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> STOP BROWSING FOR TETHER DEVICES event received from airportd
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Reviewing nearby PH results: {(
    <CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a344e140> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]
)}
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Adding PH [<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a344e140> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Derived preferred PH candidates: (
    "<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a344e140> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]",
    "<CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a344e140> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]"
)
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Show user notification for <CWTetherDevice: 0x7f90a344e140> [deviceID=2B84B541-BD98-43A8-907C-EE508376DE5A, deviceName=iPhone, batteryLife=61, signalStrength=3, networkType=6, deviceGroup=1]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-HOTSPOT COMPLETED for interface en0, took 5.0108 seconds, returned 'failure', show user notification
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> AUTO-JOIN COMPLETED for interface en0, took 5.0144 seconds, returned result 'failure', error [NO ERROR]
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCInterfaceContext __scheduleAutoJoinRetryWithInterval:]: Auto-join will retry in 10.000000 seconds.
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> -[CWAutoHotspotNotifications showAutoHotspotNotificationForTetherDevice:retry:interfaceName:]_block_invoke: Notification is already pending/delivered for this interface. Ignoring.
Info: <airportd[2353]> TIMEOUT WiFiAgent took longer than 30 seconds to reply to CWEventTypeEnableTetherDevice event
Info: <airportd[2353]> -[CWXPCSubsystem __connectToTetherDevice:remember:interfaceName:authorization:connection:error:]: Failed to enable hotspot device, returned error Error Domain=com.apple.wifi.apple80211API.error Code=-3905 "(null)"
AutoJoin: <airportd[2353]> Failed to connect to tether device 'iPhone', took 30.0147 seconds, returned error [-3905, com.apple.wifi.apple80211API.error, 'Timeout']
BTC: <airportd[2353]> __BluetoothCoexHandleUpdateForNode: <en0> Handle Bluetooth Coex: FrequencyBand <0>, Bluetooth Bandwidth Utilization <8>, Clamshell Mode <0>
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> current=(no_assoc) changed=(join)
Info: <WiFiAgent[389]> QUERY CACHED SCAN RESULTS request received from pid 307 (SystemUIServer)
BTC: <airportd[2353]> BluetoothCoexSetProfile: <en0> profile for band 2.4GHz didn't change
BTC: <airportd[2353]> BluetoothCoexSetProfile: <en0> profile for band 5GHz didn't change
BTC: <airportd[2353]> BluetoothCoexHandle_ApplyPolicy: <en0> Bluetooth Coex: band = 0xc
BTC: <airportd[2353]> BluetoothCoexHandle_ApplyPolicy: <en0> Bluetooth Coex: hosting AP = NO, assoc as STA = NO, assoced in 2.4GHz = NO
Info: <airportd[2353]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
Info: <airportd[2353]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 389 (WiFiAgent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve the issue by performing another PRAM reset. The first one must have been unsuccessful.